# dotnet452 conflicts with dotnet46

Tags: 20.04, winetricks, dotnet

I have to run a windows msi installer application that demands .NET Framework 4.5.2 to be installed in the system.
Now in my system few versions of .NET framework are already installed namely 4.6, 3.5 and 4.8 are already installed. But I am unable to install version 4.5.2 because it conflicts with version 4.6 which is already installed. I am posting the commands I entered and the output, if anyone can answer how to proceed, it will be a great help (Thank you in advance):

```
winetricks dotnet452
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Using winetricks 20200412 - sha256sum: 7651c93e39fcb080483c38836513bf912273a87ea97d137f6b958ed3d9628c3d with wine-6.0-rc4 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call dotnet452
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.


error: dotnet452 conflicts with dotnet46, which is already installed. You can run `/usr/bin/winetricks --force dotnet452` to ignore this check and attempt installation.


~ took 2s 
❯ /usr/bin/winetricks --force dotnet452
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Using winetricks 20200412 - sha256sum: 7651c93e39fcb080483c38836513bf912273a87ea97d137f6b958ed3d9628c3d with wine-6.0-rc4 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call dotnet452
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing load_dotnet452 

This package (dotnet452) may not fully work on a 64-bit installation. 32-bit prefixes may work better.

Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing load_remove_mono 
0164:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0164:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
01c0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
01c0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.

Mono does not appear to be installed.

Executing w_do_call dotnet40
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing load_dotnet40 

This package (dotnet40) may not fully work on a 64-bit installation. 32-bit prefixes may work better.


dotnet40 does not yet fully work or install on wine.  Caveat emptor.

Current Wine does not have Wine bug 42701, so not applying workaround
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing load_remove_mono 
03f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
03f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
04fc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
04fc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.

Mono does not appear to be installed.

Executing w_do_call winxp
Executing mkdir -p /home/chess

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing load_winxp 
05a4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
05a4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
05c8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
05c8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
The operation completed successfully
Setting Windows version to winxp
Executing wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\set-winver.reg
0628:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0628:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0498:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0498:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
Executing wine64 regedit C:\windows\Temp\set-winver.reg
0584:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0584:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
049c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
049c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.

Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/chess/.wine terminate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. After some search I found the following link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

It says that one must not install the previous version in 4x series if a newer version is already installed. Now I have to try to uninstall 4.6 and 4.8 and then install 4.5.2.